# Having some difficulties running xv6 under qemu

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system, qemu, xv6

I found a lot of threads listing their troubles with getting xv6 to run, but couldn't really find any that helped me, so here we go...

The first step of running the make command didn't give me any problems.

However when I tried to run the "make qemu" command, I got the following error:

[error1(it didn't let me embed the image for some reason, so i have linked the screenshot from imgur instead)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpXGL.png)

I am using a 64 bit ubuntu system, so I tried installing a 32 bit directory using sudo apt-get install libc6-dev:i386

Then I uncommented line 54 in my makefile, which was basically "QEMU = qemu-system-i386". Running make qemu now gave me this error:

[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzkI0.png)

I then changed that line to "QEMU = qemu-system-x86_64" and got this error:

[error3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bHMc.png)

I am completely lost here and would really appreciate some help...

Comment: How do you installed `qemu`?

Answer (score 0):

All those messages are telling you variants of the same thing: you don't have QEMU installed, and therefore the makefile is unable to run it. Try installing it...